# How to get the new value of an HTML input after a keypress has modified it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML input box

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar">
```

I've attached a handler for the '*keyup*' event, but if I retrieve the current value of the input box during the event handler, I get the value as it was, and not as it will be!

I've tried picking up '*keypress*' and '*change*' events, same problem.

I'm sure this is simple to solve, but at present I think the only solution is for me to use a short timeout to trigger some code a few milliseconds in the future!

*Is there anyway to obtain the current value during those events?*

EDIT: looks like I had a caching problem with my js file as I checked the same code later on and it worked just fine. I would delete the question, but not sure if that loses rep for the kind folk who posted ideas :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Can you post your code? I'm not finding any issue with this. Tested on Firefox 3.01/safari 3.1.2 with:

```
function showMe(e) {
// i am spammy!
  alert(e.value);
}
....
<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar" onkeyup="showMe(this)" />
```

Comment: I came home, checked my code out of subversion, and it worked just fine. I think I must have had a caching problem with the js file and it was stuck on handling keypress rather than keyup. Appreciate the effort in writing sample code so marking this as the answer :)

Answer (score 22):

To give a ***modern*** approach to this question. This works well, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. [GlobalEventHandlers.oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput).

```
var onChange = function(evt) {
  console.info(this.value);
  // or
  console.info(evt.target.value);
};
var input = document.getElementById('some-id');
input.addEventListener('input', onChange, false);
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two kinds of input value: field's **property** and field's html **attribute**.

If you use keyup event and field.value you shuld get current value of the field. 
It's not the case when you use field.getAttribute('value') which would return what's in the html attribute (value=""). The property represents what's been typed into the field and changes as you type, while attribute doesn't change automatically (you can change it using field.setAttribute method).

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function callme(field) {
            alert("field:" + field.value);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="f1">
            <input type="text" onkeyup="callme(this);" name="text1">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It looks like you can use the onkeyup to get the **new** value of the HTML input control.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) is a table of the different events and the levels of browser support. You need to pick an event which is supported across at least all modern browsers.

As you will see from the table, the `keypress` and `change` event do not have uniform support whereas the `keyup` event does.

Also make sure you attach the event handler using a cross-browser-compatible method...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code (requires jQuery):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#foo').keyup(function(e) {
                var v = $('#foo').val();
                $('#debug').val(v);
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="foo" value="bar"><br>
        <textarea id="debug"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```