# Get Current Value of Input Element Using XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath

How do I get the current value of an input element using XPath. The value attribute is the initial value of the input, not the current one.

Here's an example of what I was hoping would work, but it prints "Initial value" even after the value is changed.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yx29os71/2/)

```
<input id="value-input" value="Initial value">
<button onclick="onButtonClicked()">
Print Value
</button>
```

```
function onButtonClicked () {
  const value = document.evaluate('//input[@id="value-input"]/@value', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: No. I'm trying to get an input with a specific value for a UI test. I need to be able to do something like //div/input[@value="expected value"]

Comment: Oh... I thought you're using Selenium to extract value... Did you try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222740/how-to-get-the-new-value-of-an-html-input-after-a-keypress-has-modified-it)?

Comment: That won't work because I need to use XPath. I'm using nightwatch.js for testing.

Comment: The attribute value of the `value` attribute in your code stays at `Initial value`. You need to change it to something else before evaluating it.

Comment: I'm testing a third party component, so I can't reasonably change the attributes value.

Comment: My understanding from looking into this so far is that in the DOM node, the value property is set to the text entered into the input, but the input element's value attribute overrides this.